# Modules Communication in Modulare Monolith architecture

Tags: module, domain-driven-design, bounded-contexts, servicecontract, modular-monolith

I'm currently looking how to build a Modular Monolith application using DDD principles [here a good blog that explain the concept](https://www.kamilgrzybek.com/design/modular-monolith-primer/).
Let's imagine I want my  modules to communicate using direct call trough an injected interface/service by example.

Obviously I can not directly call the domain service of the other module as it potentially exposes some internal domain model objects.
That means that a different interface and set of needed objects should be exposed. Also a translation layer  would be then necessary  (by example in the case of an ACL pattern to translate the domain object to some  sharable dto).
The question is how this should be designed and implemented?

By example, where does the shared data and services must be defined? Where and how the translation layer should be implemented?

I was thinking to have a global project/module exposing all the contracts interfaces but I'm not sure is the right choice.

Thanks